# Include VF page and Lightning Components on all the pages?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have a visualforce page and a lightning component which I want to embed on all the Salesforce pages. Just the chat window/dial phone pin in service console which appears on all the Satndard Salesforce pages I want to :-

1. Embed the vf page on all the standard page in Salesforce classic.
2. Embed the lightning component/app in all the standard pages in Salesforce lightning.
3. Or embed the vf page or lightning component in all the standard Salesforce pages in classic and lightning.

Any suggestion would be very helpful.